# How to order simpleXML loop

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I neeed to order my loop by the id

my xml doc looks like this

```
<gig id="16">
        <date>Fri. 23rd Apr</date>
        <venue>Sneaky Pete's</venue>
        <area>Edinburgh</area>
        <telephone>www.ticketweb.co.uk</telephone>  
        <price>£10</price>
        <time>Time TBA</time>
    </gig>
```

So as you can see  I need to order my string by this id

my code for the output is

```
<?php 
foreach ($xml->gig as $dateof){
echo '<tr><td><img src="images/arrow.jpg" /></td><td width="200px" class="loop-Date">' . $dateof->date . '</td><td width="700px">' . $dateof->venue . '</td></tr>';
}
?>
```

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
foreach ($xml->gig as $gig) {
   $id = (int)$gig->attributes()->id;
   $array[$id] = $gig;
}
```

Order by ID: `ksort($array);`

```
foreach ($array as $id => $gig) {
   echo '<tr><td><img src="images/arrow.jpg" /></td><td width="200px" class="loop-Date">' . (string)$gig->date . '</td><td width="700px">' . (string)$gig->venue . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Never forget to cast the SimpleXMLObjects to Strings (or Integers, ...).

Comment: You were faster than me :) BTW: In the second line of the second block you need to replace `$dateof` into `$gig`.

Comment: Thanks Veger for that.

Thanks r3zn1k for your help :-)

Comment: I cannot seem to get it working it just display's blank , no error's just looks like it's not getting the values ?????

Comment: The attribute should be read via array access, no need to call attributes() -- `$id = (int) $gig['id'];`

Comment: Could you explain a little josh :)

Comment: Instead of using `$gig->attributes()->id` you can use `$gig['id']`. That's how SimpleXML was supposed to be used in the first place. attributes() was added later, to deal with namespaced attributes.

Comment: I didn't test it. Use "print_r($array);" to display the content of the array. What does this command return?

Comment: use "krsort" instead of "ksort"

Answer (score 0):

There's no order-by option in (standard) xpath, but in [xsl(t)](http://docs.php.net/xsl) there is e.g. [<xsl:sort>](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-sort)

Answer (score 0):

I often see requests to sort XML elements, generally based on the result of an XPath query.

For that purpose I've written a method, sortedXPath(), for [SimpleDOM](http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/). It has the same signature as [array_multisort()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) except that the first argument is an XPath expression and instead of using array keys it uses XPath expressions. For example, here's how to retrieve all `<gig/>` elements, sorted by their `id` attribute:

```
include 'SimpleDOM.php';

$gigs = simpledom_load_string(
    '<gigs>
        <gig id="16">
            <date>Fri. 23rd Apr</date>
        </gig>
        <gig id="15">
            <date>Fri. 16th Apr</date>
        </gig>
    </gigs>'
);

foreach ($gigs->sortedXPath('//gig', '@id') as $gig)
{
    echo 'gig id ', $gig['id'], ' - date: ', $gig->date, "\n";
}
```